# db.collection findOne by id runs but doesn't return

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm using the [node mongo db native module](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) and i'm having difficult with the findOne.

When i run:

```
let collection = db.collection('eventschemas')

collection.find({}).toArray(function(error, result) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  console.log(result);
});
```

The result will be:

```
[ { _id: 56b644a1bc8f66ce59322b38,
    type: 'events',
    attributes: 
     { hiw: [Object],
       title: 'Pub Crawl',
       'meeting-point': 'Ponto de encontro',
       information: '1h de Open Bar',
       'women-price': 40,
       'men-price': 60,
       end: Sat Feb 13 2016 17:08:00 GMT-0200 (BRST),
       start: Sat Feb 13 2016 17:07:59 GMT-0200 (BRST),
       'updated-at': Sat Feb 06 2016 17:08:54 GMT-0200 (BRST),
       'created-at': Sat Feb 06 2016 17:08:17 GMT-0200 (BRST),
       'is-active': true },
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I just have one event, so it's the right result. But when i run:

```
let collection = db.collection('eventschemas')

collection.findOne({ _id: '56b644a1bc8f66ce59322b38' }, function(error, result) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  console.log(result);
});
```

The result will be null, what doesn't make sense. Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the `_id` string in **[`ObjectID()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)**:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    id = new ObjectID('56b644a1bc8f66ce59322b38'); // wrap in ObjectID

let collection = db.collection('eventschemas')

collection.findOne({ _id: id }, function(error, result) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log(result);
});
```